# Sheet API writing with javascript failing

Tags: ajax, api, google-sheets-api

i am trying to write to google sheet cell using ajax. The read code below is working fine:

```
var sheetId="MY_SHEET_ID";
var sheetName="MY_SHEET_Name";
var API_Key="MY_API_KEY";
xhr.open("GET","https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+sheetId+"/values/"+sheetName+"?key="+API_Key+"",true);
```

But the write code isnt:

```
var values = [["ABC"]]; 
xhr.open("PUT","https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+sheetId+"/values/"+values+"/"+sheetName+"!c2?key="+API_Key+"&valueInputOption=RAW",true);
```

Comment: For Sheets API, it can use GET method with API key. Unfortunately, the API key cannot be used for POST and PUT methods. It may be due to the security. Please use OAuth2 and service account.

Comment: can you clarify how i can do that? what should the the url structure be after i get OAuth2 token?

Comment: The endpoint is the same with your question. Please add the access token to the headers, instead of API key.